# Serving static content from a subdomain in asp.net using URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, static, url-rewriting, subdomain

Searched for a few hours with no avail so here goes...

I have a domain which is receiving quite a few hits per day and have been asked if I can serve the static content from a subdomain. As the site is quite extensive and already written, I was wondering if there is any way I can use URL rewriting to change:

www.example.com/image.gif

to

static.example.com/image.gif

I have a solution which works using 301 redirects but from what I understand, this is counter productive as 2 requests will have to be made per image. I don't really want to go through all the aspx pages and css to hard code the new url as it will cause problems further down the line - some parts of the site are still being developed and static content could change at any time. I tried using rewrite (as opposed to redirect) to change the url but it came out something like:

http://www.example.com/http://static.example.com/image.gif

How would you achieve this? I have full access to dns and the server (win 2008r2 / IIS 7.5) so can make any changes if url rewriting is not the answer.

Thanks in advance

Tom.

Comment: Do you already have the site http://static.example.com/ configured and working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using an HttpModule. The following example captures all requests for gif files, and changes the absolute path to point to your alternate site that hosts the static content. Try this method inside of a HttpModule:

```
    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
        // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fullPath = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string fileExtension = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".gif"))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
            context.Response.Redirect(fullPath.Replace("www.example.com", "static.example.com"));
        }
    }
```

For more about HttpModule, go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

I tested the above code - it works. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much, requests are now being redirected properly although one image is being serverd as text/html!? Does this method not incur 2 requests per image as well as it looks like it sends a 302?

Comment: I noticed yesterday that it gives a 302 response for the original image request, and a 200 for redirected file (I setup a demo file in the redirected location, hence the 200). That should be fine, unless you want to avoid it for some reason. I'm not sure about the text/html issue. Is there any obvious difference between that image and the rest?

Comment: Tom, you should be able to set the content type explicitly.  See my answer above - I added a line within the if block.

Comment: One other thing: there is a better solution to change the domain that using Replace() on the fullPath string above. If I get a chance later today, I will update the code with a more ideal solution.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of came up with a similar solution regarding the content type and no, the image is no different! Must just be one of those weird bugs. It turns out it's actually faster not to use a static domain in this case. Maybe the combination of 302 and response.replace outweights any potential speed increase. Shall I wait for another solution before I mark this as answered?

Comment: Regarding marking as answered, that's up to you. Another way to accomplish the task of referencing images on a separate domain would be to take the original web page response, and update the paths on it using regex before it gets pushed. That would avoid the two requests for every image (which adds overhead). Even then, I'm not sure your ultimate goal of faster speeds would be accomplished. All in all, you may just need to break-down add a new server and setup load balancing (should be relatively easy to do with Win2008 R2 - go check out serverfault.com if you need help in that area).

Comment: Interesting thought about load balancing, its not something we've looked into yet. I'll certainly take a look. Thanks for the help, im going to mark as answered as it did work and I learned something new which is always good.