# URL rewrite IIS for static.example.com

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm developing in ASP.NET and having serveral applications with this folder structure:

```
WWW
 -> IMG
 -> CSS
 -> JS
 -> ASPX
```

So for example:

```
www1.example.com/IMG/file.png
```

My target is to rewrite all incoming requests to a subdomain for IMG, CSS and JS.
So that:

```
www1.example.com/IMG/file.png
```

Or

```
www2.example.com/IMG/file.png
```

would become to:

```
static.example.com/IMG/file.png
```

They should use their own folders in their own sites. It should just be routed through static.example.com. I know I can do so with Apache but I do not have any experience with IIS so far.

How is this technically possible? I have total rights on my IIS 7.5. There are several applications with the same structure and I want to use each ones IMG, CSS and JS folder. Do I have a performance increasement?

**EDIT: 28.10.2014**

Hopefully it gets a little bit clearer with this image. Thanks for your answers, it helped me a lot! So I can rewrite my URL to  "static.server.com" and now I want the image from the right source which could be either www1.server.com/img/abc.png OR www2.server.com/img/abc.png. The static website shouldn't have a real path it should just be a blank website which listens on host headers or post/get to deliver images, css and javascript from the right source.
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108364/serving-static-content-from-a-subdomain-in-asp-net-using-url-rewrite)** you can use httpmodule. So you can use the code from the same question and amend it to your requirement.

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
    string fullPath = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    string fileExtension = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
    if (fileExtension.Equals(".gif"))
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        context.Response.Redirect(fullPath.Replace("www.example.com", "static.example.com"));
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can have something like this in your `web.config` file

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Forward to static file server">
            <match url="^.+\.(?:jpg|bmp|gif)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://static_file_server/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

More info **[here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)**

Comment: Is it also possible to do so via Web.conf? I don't want to do so on code side as it should be hostable and also running as standalone software.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I don't know what your actual use case is (or may have misread your question), so this is a "simple/r" option:

- DNS (you will need this regardless) and;
- yes, hostheaders if you are sharing IPs.

No modules/redirects, and such - which IMHO should already be a sign that you're adding:

- more requests (redirects)
- adding more for your application to do (httpmodule that inspects **each** request)

Hth...

Comment: sry replying you so late...
My usecase is that I have multiple applications outside which use the same CSS, JS and images. I'd like to share the files with the benefit of a subdomain for performance improvement.